# What is the error in this shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I never used shell script, but now I have to  , here is what I'm trying to do :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo running the program 
./first 
var = ($(ls FODLDER |wc -l))    #check how many files the folder contains 
echo $var
if( ["$var" -gt "2"] #check if  there are more the 2file 
then ./second 
fi
```

the scriopt crashes at the `if` statement. how may I solve this

Comment: Explain your goal first, then put your code. And check your syntax on http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: the IF statment should be `if [ "$var" -gt 2 ]; then ./second` take a look at this link http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/unix-shell-scripting/ifelse-tutorial.php

Comment: @Engine downvote button is for _"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear…"_ you're asking for the error while you should be providing one and you obviously didn't try to fix it yourself as there is even typo in the middle of your code

Comment: WOW  sorry for mentioning that I've never used shell

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez your being abit silly he clearly tried to code the script himself and made a few syntax mistakes everyones does it at some point and if you’re going to give out then why bother answering at all.

Comment: ? He asked why he got a downvote and @ÉdouardLopez obligingly explained to him what it means.  Perhaps there should also be a link to http://stackoverflow.com/help and/or to the [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in Help, but really, if you don't familiarize yourself with StackOverflow before you dive in, don't act surprised when you get ... feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many:

```
var = ($(ls FODLDER |wc -l))
```

This is wrong, you cannot have those spaces around `=`.

```
if( ["$var" -gt "2"]
```

Your `(` is not doing anything there, so it has to be deleted. Also, you need spaces around `[` and `]`.

All together, this would make more sense:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "running the program"
./first 
var=$(find FOLDER -maxdepth 1 -type f|wc -l) # better find than ls
echo "$var"
if [ "$var" -gt "2" ]; then
    ./second 
fi
```

Note:

- quote whenever you `echo`, specially when handling variables.
- see another way to look for files in a given path. [Parsing ls is kind of evil](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).
- indent your code for better readibility.

Comment: thanks to you for your help, sorry but I'm comming from the C world I never thoough that space could matter.

I have to wait 7 min to accept you answer

Comment: No problem! It happens to the best of us :) Try to read some tutorial, for example the one Eduard suggests in his answer and keep trying!

Comment: A fun alternative to the find (which could output a bigger number if files contain "newline" in their names, etc) : you could use: `var=$(cd /the/dir && set -- * && echo "$#")` to get the number of files (unless you have too many of them in the dir, and "*" can't be expanded fully or goes above the shell's limitations). Problem is it also counts non-files (but so does the OP's example)

Comment: +1! One comment: In the oroginal OP's intent, the `ls | wc` counts the directories too, so, maybe removing the `-type f` from the find and adding the `-mindepth 1` to avoid including `.` in a case of `find .` :)

Comment: When we talking about the _fun alternatives_ : After the `eval "$(stat -s .)"` the `echo $(($st_nlink -2))` gives the exact count of "entries" in the directory.. ;)

Comment: @Engine you can check good comments by Olivier Dulac and jm666 regarding how to count the number of files / elements in FOLDER directory.

Comment: @OlivierDulac any link to `*` expansion limit?

Comment: @&#201;douardLopez : no portable answer for that: best is to test for your implementation. And beware both rhe numver of entries and/or their overall size can reach some limit

Answer (score 2):

Edit your *script.bash* file as follow:

```
#!/bin/env bash
dir="$1"

echo "running the program"
./first 
dir_list=( $dir/* )    # list files in directory
echo ${#dir_list[@]}     # count files in array
if (( ${#dir_list[@]} > 2 )); then # test how many files
  ./second 
fi
```

### Usage

```
script.bash /tmp/
```

### Explaination

You need to **[learn bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) to avoid dangerous actions!**

1. pass the directory to work with as first argument in the command line (`/tmp/` → `$1)
2. use [glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/globbing) to create an array (`dir_list`) containing all file in given directory
3. count items in array (`${#dir_list[@]}`)
4. test the number of item using [arithmetic context](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression).

Comment: @fedorqui thanks, another proof against copy/paste :P